# How can I prevent clogs in a section of pipe with reverse slope due to soil settling?

Tags: plumbing

A plumber stopped my basement from flooding by clearing the outdoor drain, but he said that the outdoor trap was tilted, presumably because the ground settled. This means the water has to flow uphill, and solid waste gets stuck and clogs the drain. How long until it clogs again? Also, is there anything I can do to avoid clogs while I arrange to have the trap leveled? Is it feasible to follow WikiHow's [suggestion of using a drain rod](https://www.wikihow.com/Unblock-Outdoor-Drains)?

Comment: `How long until it clogs again?` ... why do you think that this is answerable by anyone here?

Comment: Please tell us more about this plumbing. What is an "outdoor drain"? Why is the trap outside? We can't help without a clear picture.

Comment: It will probably be quite a while before it clogs again if you're very vigilant and clean it regularly, however, it could be later this afternoon if some neighborhood ragamuffins come stuff something in it. Of course, that's just a guess...

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here is prevention.  Determine where the debris that is clogging your drain is coming from and stop it from getting into the pipe to begin with.

Comment: Almost any drain has "debris" in the form of sediment. What is your specific suggestion for preventing sedimentary clogging?

Comment: I lived in a house where a previous homeowner solved this problem as @jwh20 suggests -- the house was slightly out-of-level and a staircase from the basement to the back yard had a drain that was clogging.  In my case, it was actually connected to a kitchen drain, and debris from the kitchen would clog it!  My point is, the outdoor drain wasn't the only way for debris to build up.  Previous homeowner's solution was to place a tin roof over the basement walk-up so rain no longer got into that drain at all.  It worked well.

Comment: @isherwood how about periodic power flushing?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're tagging me here. My point was that the answer is incomplete.